# linux qt QWidget::create runs error

Tags: linux, qt, qwidget

I am developing a project using qt under linux OS where a qt Qwidget needs to setparent to a native window belonging to other processes. The native window is not deleloped by me.So I cannot get its source and change it.

I find a method in:
http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/0.6/qxtwindowsystem.html

```
class NativeWindow : public QWidget {
    public:
        NativeWindow(WId wid) {
            QWidget::create(wid, false, false); // window, initializeWindow, destroyOldWindow
        }
        ~NativeWindow() {
            QWidget::destroy(false, false); // destroyWindow, destroySubWindows
        }
};

WindowList windows = QxtWindowSystem::windows();
QStringList titles = QxtWindowSystem::windowTitles();
bool ok = false;
QString title = QInputDialog::getItem(0, "Choose Window", "Choose a window to be hid:", titles, 0, false, &ok);
if (ok)
{
    int index = titles.indexOf(title);
    if (index != -1)
    {
        NativeWindow window(windows.at(index));
        window.hide();
    }
}
```

It notes:

Note: The underlying window system might or might not allow one to alter states of windows belonging to other processes.

When I do like this, I receive an error as excepted:

```
X Error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) 3
Major opcode :3(X_GetWindowAttributes)
Resource id: 0x805cff4
```

So, how can I let window system allow me to alter states of windows belonging to other processes in linux?

Comment: What window manager are you using? Have you tried using a different one?

Comment: @scai I use gnome. To change the window manager is not a good solution beacuse the process should run on differnet environments. I thick the window system stops me from altering states of other windows is reasonable.So I should find out the configure way.

Comment: @UmNyobe No. wmctrl is command line tool that can be used to interact with an X Window manager. How should I use it?

Comment: I have already reached the goal using XReparentWindow. You'd better call XReparentWindow after you call QWidget::show, otherwise may occur other unexcepted errors.

Comment: good! add an answer with your solution so others can eventually use it in the future

Comment: QX11EmbedWidget::embedInto(WId) is also a solution for window imbeding in linux qt<br> http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qx11embedwidget.html